# Python evaluates 0 as False

Tags: python, boolean

In the Python console:

```
>>> a = 0
>>> if a:
...   print "L"
... 
>>> a = 1
>>> if a:
...   print "L"
... 
L
>>> a = 2
>>> if a:
...   print "L"
... 
L
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: That's pretty much true of any scripting language, unless you do a strict comparison to check value **AND** type.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329582/how-do-you-remember-if-1-for-true-or-false?rq=1

Comment: In python `0,"",(),{}` are considered as False values.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In Python, `bool` is a subclass of `int`, and `False` has the value `0`; even if values weren't implicitly cast to `bool` in an `if` statement (which they are), `False == 0` is true.

Comment: `0 == False` is true but not completely relevant, `None == False` is false, but `if None:` is still *evaluated* as a falsy value (along with empty mapping etc.)

Answer (score 16):

0 is a falsy value in python

Falsy values: [from (2.7) documentation:](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

> zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0L, 0.0, 0j.

Answer (score 9):

Whatever is inside an `if` clause implicitly has `bool` called on it.  So,

```
if 1:
   ...
```

is really:

```
if bool(1):
   ...
```

and `bool` calls `__nonzero__`<sup>1</sup> which says whether the object is `True` or `False`

Demo:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val
    def __nonzero__(self):
        print "here"
        return bool(self.val)

a = foo(1)
bool(a)  #prints "here"
if a:    #prints "here"
    print "L"  #prints "L" since bool(1) is True.
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>`__bool__` on python3.x</sup>

Comment: As a side note, I believe that `__nonzero__` is changed to `__bool__` in py3k.

Comment: I see it the other way around, true corresponds to 1, and is a subclass of int

Answer (score 0):

I think it just judges by 0 or not 0:

```
>>> if 0:
    print 'aa'

>>> if not 0:
    print 'aa'


aa
>>>
```

Comment: What is this meant to show? You `print` the same output for both conditions and don't explain anything

Comment: @Chris_Rands there's no print if `if 0`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, everything in python is an object. Therefore, your 0 is also an object, specifically, a built-in object.

Here are the built-in objects considered as false:

1. constants defined to be false: None and False.
2. zero of any numeric type: 0, 0.0, 0j, Decimal(0), Fraction(0, 1)
3. empty sequences and collections: '', (), [], {}, set(), range(0)

So when you put 0 in an if or while condition, or in a Boolean operation, it is tested for truth value.

```
# call the __bool__ method of 0
>>> print((0).__bool__())
False

# 
>>> if not 0:
...     print('if not 0 is evaluated as True')
'if not 0 is evaluated as True'
```