# Checking values surrounding "b" in a matrix

Tags: python, matrix, minesweeper

Minesweeper, still. 
I found a way to do it, but I know there has to be a simplified way to doing this. I have to place a number in the matrix to represent how many bombs ("b") are surrounding it. This is what I have and I know there has to be a shorter way.

```
def check(y,x):
    if ((y < 0) or (y >= len(mat1)) or (x < 0) or (x >= len(mat1))):
        return (False)
    else:
        return mat1[y][x]

def addscores():
    for x in range(len(mat1)):
        for y in range(len(mat1)):
            if mat1[y][x] != "b":
                if check(y-1,x-1) == "b" or check(y,x-1) == "b" or check(y+1,x-1) == "b" or check(y+1,x) == "b" or check(y+1,x+1) == "b" or check(y,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x) =="b":
                    mat1[y][x] = 1
                if check(y-1,x-1) == "b":
                    if check(y,x-1) == "b" or check(y+1,x-1) == "b" or check(y+1,x) == "b" or check(y+1,x+1) == "b" or check(y,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x) == "b":
                        mat1[y][x] = 2
                if check(y,x-1) == "b":
                    if check(y+1,x-1) == "b" or check(y+1,x) == "b" or check(y+1,x+1) == "b" or check(y,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x) == "b":
                        mat1[y][x] = 2
                if check(y+1,x-1) == "b":
                    if check(y+1,x) == "b" or check(y+1,x+1) == "b" or check(y,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x) == "b":
                         mat1[y][x] = 2
                if check(y+1,x) == "b":
                    if check(y+1,x+1) == "b" or check(y,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x) == "b":
                        mat1[y][x] = 2
                if check(y+1,x+1) == "b":
                    if check(y,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x) == "b":
                        mat1[y][x] = 2
                if check(y,x+1) == "b":
                    if check(y-1,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x) == "b":
                        mat1[y][x] = 2
                if check(y-1,x+1) == "b":
                    if check(y-1,x) == "b":
                        mat1[y][x] = 2
                if check(y-1,x-1) == "b":
                    if check(y,x-1) == "b":
                        if check(y+1,x-1) == "b" or check(y+1,x) == "b" or check(y+1,x+1) == "b" or check(y,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x) == "b":
                            mat1[y][x] = 3
                    if check(y+1,x-1) == "b":
                        if check(y+1,x) == "b" or check(y+1,x+1) == "b" or check(y,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x) == "b":
                            mat1[y][x] = 3
                    if check(y+1,x) == "b":
                        if check(y+1,x+1) == "b" or check(y,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x) == "b":
                            mat1[y][x] = 3
                    if check(y+1,x+1) == "b":
                        if check(y,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x) == "b":
                            mat1[y][x] = 3
                    if check(y,x+1) == "b":
                        if check(y-1,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x) == "b":
                            mat1[y][x] = 3
                if check(y-1,x-1) == "b":
                    if check(y,x-1) == "b":
                        if check(y+1,x-1) == "b":
                            if check(y+1,x) == "b" or check(y+1,x+1) == "b" or check(y,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x) == "b":
                                mat1[y][x] = 4
                    if check(y+1,x-1) == "b":
                        if check(y+1,x) == "b":
                            if check(y+1,x+1) == "b" or check(y,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x) == "b":
                                mat1[y][x] = 4
                    if check(y+1,x) == "b":
                        if check(y+1,x+1) == "b":
                            if check(y,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x+1) == "b" or check(y-1,x) == "b":
                                mat1[y][x] = 4
                    #ETC
```

Comment: You should really look into [`numpy`](http://numpy.scipy.org/) for this.  Also, you declared a function within a `for` loop--very bad practice.  I moved it out for you.

Comment: I've noticed, by the way, that you've asked 5 questions so far on SO and you haven't accepted answers for any of them so far.  You should go back over this question and the others and accept the best answer, if you want people to continue answering your questions.

Answer (score 2):

```
def check(y,x):
    if ((y < 0) or (x < 0) or (y >= len(mat1)) or (x >= len(mat1))):
        return False
    else:
        if mat1[y][x] == 'b':
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

def check_all(y,x):
    if mat1[y][x] != 'b':        
        return sum([check(y + yy, x + xx) for xx in range(-1,2) for yy in range(-1,2)])
    else:
        return 'b'

def addscores():
    for x in range(len(mat1)):
        for y in range(len(mat1)):
            mat1[y][x] = check_all(y,x)
```

If I've understood what you're doing correctly, this code--particularly the `check_all` function--should take care of your issue.  You were right, there is definitely a shorter way of doing it, using loops (or list comprehensions, in this case) rather than having to write out each check individually.

I preserved your code where possible since I don't have enough context to know if making changes will break anything.

Comment: Why is the sum of `False` and `1` equal to `1`?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497199/python-evaluates-0-as-false).  Python `bool` subclasses `int`, and `False` has a value of 0.  `True` has a value of 1.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
def add_scores():
    def bounded_range(i):
        return range(max(0, i - 1), min(len(mat1) - 1, x + 1))

    for x in range(len(mat1)):
        for y in range(len(mat1)):
            Xs = bounded_range(x)
            Ys = bounded_range(y)
            mat1[x][y] = len([0 for _x in Xs for _y in Ys
                    if not (x == _x and y == _x) and mat1[_x][_y] == 'b'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to figure out how to program Minesweeper, you can check out [MineSweep](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577365/) on the Python Cookbook which shows a twelve-step process in developing a GUI version of the game.