# Python all() function not indicating true when the list is identical

Tags: python, list, boolean

I have a list of floats and I want to check if they are all zero. Therefore I am trying to implement it with the all() function.

I have tried with one method that in my theory should work but doesnt:

```
test = [0, 0.4, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.21052631578947367, 0.4, 0.21052631578947367, 0.21052631578947367, 0.4, 0.21052631578947367]
all(test) == 0

>>> True
```

In the case above, the output should be `False`, however, I am not sure why it is `True`.

The method below is the one that works.

```
test = [0, 0.4, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.21052631578947367, 0.4, 0.21052631578947367, 0.21052631578947367, 0.4, 0.21052631578947367]
all(x==0 for x in test)

>>> False
```

Can anyone explain this short circuit in all behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the case above (`all(test)`), the output should be `False`, however, I am not sure why it is `True`.

Because `all(test)` evaluates to `False`, which [tests as equal to `0`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12497466/7954504).

[`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) itself returns `True` if all elements of the input are truthy.  In your case, 0 is not, so the "short-circuiting" will occur when `all()` sees the 0th element, and realizes it doesn't need to proceed any further in the iterable.

One other way to express the logic you're looking for would be:

```
>>> not any(test)
False
>>> not any((0, 0, 0, 0))
True
```

But keep in mind that this will treat any falsey values (such as `None`) just as it would treat zero.  If you're looking specifically at the int zero, it doesn't hurt to be explicit.

```
>>> not any((None, False, 0, [], 0))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

The `all` and `any` functions check if an array of **booleans** contains all True or all False respectively.
In Python (and most languages), any non empty string evaluates to True, as any number distinct from 0.
In your first example, the 0 in your list is equivalent to False, so all(test) is equal to 0. 
In your second example, you're using the **list comprehension** syntax to generate a boolean array, being True where the value equals 0, and False otherwise, that is why `all` results in False (not all values are True, equal to 0)

Answer (score 0):

First version returns True if all the elements are True. 0 is False.

Second version is not correct as you think.

Output of

```
print(x==0 for x in test)
```

Will be

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fce4f84bc60>
```

Therefore, this is not what you need.

You should use [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any).

```
elements = test = [0, 0.4, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.21052631578947367, 0.4, 0.21052631578947367, 0.21052631578947367, 0.4, 0.21052631578947367]

if not any(elements):
    print('All elements are false.')
```