# Python - speeding up a for loop

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

So I am currently putting together a script which does the following steps:

1. Simulate from a poisson distribution. Say this sample results in `5` from the poisson distribution
2. From the value of the poisson distribution, simulate `5` values from a lognormal distribution
3. Repeat the above process 100k+ times
4. Apply some logic to these values to get some staistics out

The fastest way I think to do this is via a large matrix which has, down the rows each simulation and across the columns every value simulated from the lognormal distribution. With this matrix in place I can then apply the metrics I need.

Here's what I've done so far, which seems to work - however i'm a beginner at python and I think there should be a way to do this "vectorised" and without having to resort to a for-loop.

Any improvements in speed would be greatly appreciated as I ideally want to run this for 1m simulations:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import scipy.stats as sp


n_sims = 100000
MU = 3
poisson = sp.poisson(mu=MU)


#first want to sample 10000 numbers from a poisson ## this is step 1
no_clms_arr = poisson.rvs(size=n_sims)

#now for each element sampled sample a lognormal and store the results back to a matrix
result = np.zeros((n_sims,no_clms_arr.max()))

for idx,i in enumerate(no_clms_arr):
    if i == 0:
        continue # no need to do anything here
    sev_sample = sp.lognorm(50,25).rvs(i) ## this is step 2
    sev_sample = np.pad(sev_sample,(0,no_clms_arr.max()-i),'constant',constant_values=(0,0))  ## padding out so I can append back to the result matrix

    result[idx,:] = sev_sample


#now calculate some metrics ## step 4, example metric is below
lim = 5e6
xs = 2e6
np.clip(a = result-xs,a_min=0,a_max=lim).sum(axis=1).mean()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it completely vectorized as the `result` array is unnecessary so you just need to generate your random numbers and then do the clip and sum:

```
vals = sp.lognorm(50, 25).rvs(no_clms_arr.sum())
(vals - xs).clip(0, lim).sum() / n_sims
```

You can speed up your method with a for loop (assuming it is necessary to make the array `result`) by generating all of your random numbers outside of the for loop in a single call, and then assign these values to the corresponding point in `result` with a for loop, ie replace your for loop with:

```
vals = sp.lognorm(50, 25).rvs(no_clms_arr.sum())

start = 0

for i, j in enumerate(no_clms_arr):
    if j:
        result[i, :j] = vals[start: start + j]
        start += j
```

You can also replace the `.sum(axis=1).mean()` call with `.sum()/n_sims` for an additional speed up.

Timings:

```
def op(n_sims = 10000, mu = 3, lim=5e6, xs=2e6):
    poisson = sp.poisson(mu=mu)
    no_clms_arr = poisson.rvs(size=n_sims)
    result = np.zeros((n_sims,no_clms_arr.max()))
    for idx,i in enumerate(no_clms_arr):
        if i == 0:
            continue # no need to do anything here
        sev_sample = sp.lognorm(50,25).rvs(i) ## this is step 2
        sev_sample = np.pad(sev_sample,(0,no_clms_arr.max()-i),'constant',constant_values=(0,0))  ## padding out so I can append back to the result matrix
        result[idx,:] = sev_sample
    return np.clip(a = result-xs,a_min=0,a_max=lim).sum(axis=1).mean()

def nin17_vectorized(n_sims = 10000, mu=3, lim=5e6, xs=2e6):
    poisson = sp.poisson(mu=mu)
    no_clms_arr = poisson.rvs(size=n_sims)
    vals = sp.lognorm(50, 25).rvs(no_clms_arr.sum())
    return (vals - xs).clip(0, lim).sum() / n_sims


def nin17_for(n_sims = 10000, mu=3, lim=5e6, xs=2e6):
    poisson = sp.poisson(mu=mu)
    no_clms_arr = poisson.rvs(size=n_sims)
    result = np.zeros((n_sims,no_clms_arr.max()))
    vals = sp.lognorm(50, 25).rvs(no_clms_arr.sum())
    start = 0
    for i, j in enumerate(no_clms_arr):
        if j:
            result[i, :j] = vals[start: start + j]
            start += j
    return np.clip(a = result-xs,a_min=0,a_max=lim).sum() / n_sims

state = np.random.get_state()

np.random.set_state(state)
print(op())
np.random.set_state(state)
print(nin17_for())
np.random.set_state(state)
print(nin17_vectorized())

%timeit op()
%timeit nin17_for()
%timeit nin17_vectorized()
```

Output:

```
5682372.071238058
5682372.071238058
5682372.071238059
2.54 s ± 8.79 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
5.62 ms ± 87.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
1.6 ms ± 11.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Comment: Very nice approach. The one suggestion I would make is that you can get a further 1% speedup by replacing a vector subtraction with a scalar subtraction. You can do that by altering `(vals - xs).clip(0, lim).sum()` to `(vals.clip(xs, lim + xs).sum() - xs * len(vals))`

Comment: Excellent - thank you very much. Can I just ask why do we need the `if j:` part - isn't python always going to be true on that?

Comment: @user144464 it's just doing the opposite of your `if i == 0: continue`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497199/python-evaluates-0-as-false

Comment: Thank you very much - i still need the result matrix for other metrics but this is a great solution and runs very fast with 1m simulations.